# Eclipse Indigo - Unable to upgrade m2e

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

Folks,

I am trying to upgrade "Maven Integration for Eclipse" from the update site - http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e.

When the repository site is entered, Eclipse shows me that the latest version available for download is 0.12.1.20110112-1712. However, when I start the install, I get an error about existing dependency. Here are the first few lines of the error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required)    0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (epp.package.java 1.4.1.20110909-1818)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Maven Integration for Eclipse 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
    Maven Integration for Eclipse 0.12.0.20101115-1102 (org.maven.ide.eclipse 0.12.0.20101115-1102)
    This version of m2eclipse cannot be installed on top of the already installed m2eclipse. Uninstall the previous version of m2eclipse and try the install again. 1.0.0.20110607-2117 (org.maven.ide.eclipse 1.0.0.20110607-2117)
    This version of m2eclipse cannot be installed on top of the already installed m2eclipse. Uninstall the previous version of m2eclipse and try the install again. 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.maven.ide.eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717)
...
```

Ok. So I need to uninstall my older version of m2e first. I go to Help->About->Installed Software. I see the following two m2e features installed:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers-->EPP Java Package-->m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.100...
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers-->EPP Java Package-->slf4j over logback logging 1.0.100...
```

The problem is when I select any of these two items, "uninstall" remains disabled. It seems the only way to uninstall it is to uninstall the parent "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers."

Can someone please tell me what I must do?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Remove the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers package. See if that helps.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: remove the m2e package of the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do but "uninstall" is disabled. Are you saying there is some other way to remove it? Thanks. Peter

Comment: Looks like you downloaded Java developer package of Eclipse which includes Maven by default. There is no way to remove 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' that is the root package of your eclipse. You can update the entire 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' that will update Maven correspondingly.

Comment: So how  do we upgrade to m2e 1.0.1 to m2e 0.10 to run buildhelper?

Answer (score 1):

If you face this problem in RAD 8 follow the instructions here at
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113607155/RAD_m2e-Nov.pdf?version=1

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue running Eclipse Indigo 64 bit running on Windows 7.  I didn't see the m2 options in dropdowns like I had in older versions of eclipse, so I thought there was a problem and tried to uninstall it, not realizing it's built in to this version.

That was a big mistake!  All my efforts to reinstall or upgrade m2eclipse back in failed.

Finally, I used the link to read through the documentation for RAD to see which software update url to use and which files to select that Satya answered with.  Here is the [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113607155/RAD_m2e-Nov.pdf?version=1) again.

RAD apparently is close enough and that got me on the right track.  Then I found an error with "tampered files", which turned out to be related to using jdk 1.7.  The solution I found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-plugin-for-eclipse-jar-has-been-tampered/) was an easy fix, just change the installed jre to 1.6 and then the next attempt of the installation for the m2eclipse plugin went through fine.

I'm putting this information in the hopes that it will save someone time if they run into this same issue and not want to reinstall eclipse.  With all my plugins and configurations it would have taken a long time to redo everything.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue when trying to install on "**Eclipse Indigo 3.7.0**" (that came in the "Ubuntu Software Center" of **Ubuntu 11.10**).

See log below:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for
>   Eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
>   1.0.100.20110804-1717)   Missing requirement: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717
>   (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.20110804-1717) requires
>   'org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

But **Maven** works on "**Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1**".

Download mirror for "**Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1**" on **Linux 64 bit**:  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

More mirrors: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2

FYI: **MercurialEclipse** plugin also worked with "**Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1**" (after installing the **hg** command using "sudo apt-get install mercurial" on the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem coming out of **Eclipse** version. Download and install [Eclipse for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2). Run **Eclipse** Help>Eclipse Marketplace>Enter m2e and do a search. Install it with one click.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the new m2e (1.4) on helios, i had to uninstall all maven elements in eclipse and then, i could install m2e from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases".

Steps to uninstall existing maven elements ( from org.maven.ide.*) :

1. Click in Help in eclipse
2. Install New Software...
3. Click on What is already installed
4. Select all item from org.maven.ide.* (even if it's Required)
5. uninstall them all